# UML papyrus tool

Tags: papyrus

Here what i have done so far to create UML Diagrams from java code.

1. Project -> right click-> Discovery -> Discoverer -> Discover KDM code from java project model –> You’ll get a property dialog box at the serialization line make set it to TRUE that would generate a file project_KDM.xmi
2. Right click that file -> Discovery -> Discoverer -> Discover UML model from KDM code again you’ll get a property dialog set the serialization prop to TRUE to generate a file named project.UML
3. create a folder in your project and copy that UML file to it, this is because sometimes when you delete the papyrus files along with UML files it messes up with the .project file and makes your project loses the Library runtime settings so just put them in that folder instead of main project folder “/” .
4. now go to that folder you created, and pasted the UML file there, then right click on the project.uml file –> new –> papyrus model -> and finish
5. This will create empty project.di file but it in someway references the uml (I wish I knew at the moment how to import the UML file and create so many *.di files but for now I don’t so just do it the way i did)
6. ALT+W -> show view -> papyrus model explorer

I am able to generate .uml from above steps.
When i right click on .uml i can not see any option "Initialize class diagram".
Do i need to intall any plugin/tool for this?
and how can i generate UML Diagrams from this .uml using papyrus tool?

Answer (score 1):

When you have your .uml file open, you have to create diagrams in the model itself. To do that you have to open the "model explorer" view, trough usual window -> show view -> others -> Papyrus -> model explorer. Right click on a node in the explorer and select new diagram -> class diagram.